# Find usages of lombok generated builder in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, builder, lombok

I have class using Lombok builder, I can't find usages for finding lobmbok's builder methods, for example `User.builder().hasFlag()`

```
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class User {
  private boolean hasFlag;
```

I found [answer in intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744874/find-usages-of-lombok-generated-constructor-in-intellij?rq=1) but not in eclipse

Comment: did you add lombok plugin?

Comment: @cvdr yes it's working, just want to find usages of builder methods from class

Comment: In the _Outline_ view select _User > UserBuilder > hasFlag()_ and click Ctrl+Shift+H or right-click and choose _References_. Java search should work too.

Comment: @howlger it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ***Outline*** view **select *User > UserBuilder > hasFlag()*** and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (or right-click and choose *References > ...*).

Java search should work too.